# Selector doesn't work on Checkbox with vectors

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkbox

So, I've done selectors in the past and I have no idea why it doesn't work this time. I have 2 vector drawables and the plan is to change between them on click. 
I've created the following selector file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vector_favorite"
          android:state_checked="true"
          android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vector_favorite_border"
          android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

And this is my checkbox:

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/ic_phone_margin"
            android:button="@drawable/ic_favorite_selector"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_call"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

But, whenever I click it, nothing changes. I've tried with `android:checked="true"` but it's still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove `android:state_selected="true"` from your selector. It should just be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vector_favorite"
          android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vector_favorite_border"
          android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this attribute

```
app:useMaterialThemeColors="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your module-level `build.gradle`

```
 vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Add this in your Activity/Fragment

```
 static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
```

Remove Vector drawable from XML

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/ic_phone_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_call"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Set CheckBox custom drawable programmaticully like this

```
CheckBox cb = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

cb.setButtonDrawable(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_favorite_selector));
```